# What is the purpose of border in texImage2D?

Tags: webgl

The [docs for texImage2D()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) state this about `border`:

> A GLint specifying the width of the border. Must be 0.

If the border *must* be 0... what's the purpose of this parameter?

Comment: I'm guessing its in GLES for compatibility with old standard GL, and then in webgl to be compatible with ES.  Hopefully someone will be along with the real story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as visibleman mentioned, it's mostly left over from old deprecated OpenGL. It's deprecated in modern OpenGL

from the [OpenGL 4.5 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf) section 8.5.3

> An INVALID_VALUE error is generated if border is non-zero.